# Sorting DirectoryIterator on getMTime in PHP

Tags: php, sorting

I'm very new to PHP, but as a start, I've made a file deleter / lister, depending on time. If you access the page and the server finds files that are older than approx. 10 days, it will delete the file. Otherwise, it will display the file. What I'm trying to do, is sort the files that are displayed after time, so the newest come first. I've tried a variety of different approaches + searched around here, but not been able to find something that works for exactly this. I gave it a shot with directly applying

arsort($dir)

but since it's an object, it wouldn't let me. Can't really see it as a good way to sort in the for each for each item.

```
function fileDelete(){
$dir = new DirectoryIterator(dirname(__FILE__));
$now = time();
$j = 0;
foreach($dir as $fileinfo){
    if($fileinfo->getExtension() == "png"){
        if($now - filemtime($fileinfo) >= (60 * 60 * 24 * 10)){
            unlink($fileinfo);
            echo $fileinfo . " deleted " . "<br>";
            $j++;
        } else { 
            $data = getImageSize($fileinfo);
            $width = $data[0];
            $height = $data[1];

            ?> 
                <a href="../<?php echo $fileinfo ?>"><img src="<?php echo $fileinfo ?>" width="<?php echo ($width/2) ?>" height="<?php echo ($height/2) ?>"></a>
            <?php }
    }
}
if($j == 0){
    return "No files deleted";
} else {
    return "<br>" . $j . " files deleted. <br>";
}
```

}

Here is my code. I also tried to array_push() it into another array and sort that, but for some reason, it didn't work. I hope someone can give me best practice on this and sorry for the duplicate if you find any. I didn't.

Answer (score 0):

I actually fixed my own problem:
I split up the code into two foreach-loops. Made all the checks in the first one, deleted the file and then displayed the file in the next foreach loop.
To answer it fully: It was $fil[0] I was looking for.

```
function fileDelete(){
$dir = new DirectoryIterator(dirname(__FILE__));
$now = time();
$j = 0;
$filer = array();

foreach($dir as $fileinfo){
    if($fileinfo->getExtension() == "png"){
        if($now - filemtime($fileinfo) >= (60 * 60 * 24 * 10)){
            unlink($fileinfo);
            echo $fileinfo . " deleted " . "<br>";
            $j++; 
        } else {
        $filer[$fileinfo->getMTime()][] = $fileinfo->getFilename();
        }
    }   
}

arsort($filer);

foreach($filer as $fil){
            $data = getImageSize($fil[0]);
            $width = $data[0];
            $height = $data[1];

            ?> 
                <a href="../<?php echo $fil[0] ?>"><img src="<?php echo $fil[0] ?>" width="<?php echo ($width/2) ?>" height="<?php echo ($height/2) ?>"></a>
            <?php }

if($j == 0){
    return "No files deleted";
} else {
    return "<br>" . $j . " files deleted. <br>";
}
```

}